# Calculation using value from rows with matching identifier value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a very large dataframe with loads of users and associated events and times. I'd like to add a new column with the time delta for each user from a specific type of event of interest that occurs once for each user.

Example start data:

```
UserID  |   Event      |   DateTime
1       | Interest     |   12:00
2       | Other        |   12:01
1       | Other        |   12:02
2       | Interest     |   12:03
2       | Other        |   12:04
```

Basic example of what I'm looking for:

```
UserID  |   Event      |   DateTime  | TimeDelta
1       | Interest     |   12:00     |  0:00
2       | Other        |   12:01     | -0:02
1       | Other        |   12:02     |  0:02
2       | Interest     |   12:03     |  0:00
2       | Other        |   12:04     |  0:01
```

I have an iterative solution below, but I'm aware that iteration tends not to be the optimal way to work with dataframes and my solution doesn't scale to the larger datasets I'm working with. Is there a more "pandas" way to do this:

```
for uid in list_of_uids:
    event_of_interest_time = df['DateTime'][(df['UserId']==uid) & (df['Event']=='Interest')]
    df.loc[df['UserId'] == uid, 'TimeDelta'] = df.loc[df['UserId'] == uid, 'DateTime'] - event_of_interest_time.values[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like (PS, you can using transform or map to improve your speed )

```
df.groupby('uid').apply(lambda x : (x['DateTime']-(x['DateTime'][x['Event']=='Interest']).values))
Out[1902]: 
uid   
1    0            00:00:00
     2            00:02:00
2    1   -1 days +23:58:00
     3            00:00:00
     4            00:01:00
Name: DateTime, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: @fordy yw :-) happy coding